Auth failure error while using github.com/xmppo/go-xmpp package
I am using "github.com/xmppo/go-xmpp" package then error I face is auth failure: SASL negotiation is not allowed in this state.
But While I am using "github.com/mattn/go-xmpp" is working . Please help me out why this happening.
I am using ejabberd 23.1.0 and my go-xmpp vrsion is v0.2.0.
My debug log :
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream to='example.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='18386229244849438105' version='1.0' xml:lang='en' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='example.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-512-PLUS</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-512</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-256-PLUS</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-256</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512-PLUS'>cD10bHMtZXhwb3J0ZXIsLG49YWRtaW4scj1jMjk0NGRhMjk2N2RlYmJj</auth>
<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>Invalid channel binding</text></failure>
<response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>Yz1jRDEwYkhNdFpYaHdiM0owWlhJc0xLRXIwWTFwSDAxeUQyNk9JUTByMnRZOXNCVVVsUk0wZ2VuLzJXL1hVZ2dtLHI9LHA9ODgzdTlNbFVhMDRFUWpxdTZkOEdTTjJSZmR6UXpTaWs0UzFEWEk2cXl1YVlUbE9SdWV4NXZHWE5vVEU1Szc0WXN1SzhVVUY0WjhjMnNMMWdqd3M2aEE9PQ==</response>
<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>SASL negotiation is not allowed in this state</text></failure>
err: auth failure: SASL negotiation is not allowed in this state


Please provide more info (e.g. minimal reproducible example, details of the xmpp server, debug logs etc. I note that you have also raised an issue in the project.

Thanks @Brits for your response . I have add the details in question . Please check and let me know if you need more details.
